# websocket client to socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I need a server to be able to accept connections from both websocket and socket.io clients, is that possible? When I'm running just socket.io, also socket.io client works fine, but standard websocket client is unable to connect. On the other hand when I run websocket server alongside socket.io, websocket worsk well, but in browser, which is trying to connect via socket.io, I see error `WebSocket connection to ... failed: Invalid frame header`. Is it possible to get both connections working on single server instance?

I'm using [express.io](https://github.com/techpines/express.io) and [websocket-node](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node) and it would be great to get it working only with express.oi.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  socket.io is an additional protocol on top of webSocket so you can't use the same server-side code to listen to both a plain webSocket and a socket.io connection.  It would be easiest to put one of the two connections on a different port and just use a different handler for each, letting a standard library for each handle what they were built for.

Answer (score 21):

While @jfriend00 is right that socket.io is an additional protocol on top of webSocket, I found the additional protocol might be quite simple. I think socket.io@2.0.3 server implicitly runs a WebSocket server powered by [ws@2.3.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws), I managed to (with the help of F12/network tool) connect to it with a native WebSocket client.

socket.io client:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost');
socket.emit('hello', 'there');
```

websocket client:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket');
ws.send('42' + JSON.stringify(['hello', 'there']));
// ws.onmessage will get a MessageEvent object with the data property being encoded in the similar way.
```

Socket.IO API is more abstract, it deals with event and args, while WebSocket API deals with string.

Comment: What's up with `ws.send('42'...`? Is the `42` needed for any reason?

Comment: @Mobilpadde Yes, I think the number is some kind of message type. If I remember right, there is at least one another number, for "probe" message.

Comment: @Mobilpadde You can see it yourself: open https://socket.io/demos/chat/  in Chrome, in F12 > network, filter with "EIO=3&transport=websocket", there should be some of them, and the response headers should contain "Connection:upgrade", and there should be "Frames" tab in detail panel, instead of "Preview" and "Response" tabs for normal HTTP requests. The contents listed in "Frames" tab are quite intuitive, such as '2probe', '42["login", {numUsers: 10}]'. I think what browsers support here is websocket, i.e., the upgraded HTTP, not Socket.IO.

Comment: 42 is the answer to everything

Comment: Fascinating answer. Of course, in real life it just means: don't use socket.io unless your platform is supported and use the library itself instead. I'd use something like this https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp

Comment: Doesn't work for version 4

Comment: - 4 being Engine.IO "message" packet type
- 2 being Socket.IO "message" packet type

https://socket.io/docs/v4/#is-socketio-still-needed-today

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is facing issue when connecting to a socket.io server which runs version 4.x.x (i.e. engine.io version 4), refer to the following discussion of socket.io github repo:

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/discussions/4299