# NestJS WebSocket connection issue: unable to establish connection or receive data

Tags: node.js, websocket, nestjs

I'm currently working on a NestJS application where I've implemented WebSocket functionality using the **@nestjs/websockets | socket.io | @nestjs/platform-socket.io** modules.
However, I'm encountering difficulties establishing WebSocket connections.

I tried to connect both from the browser (developer console) and a small NodeJS app :

### Connection from Chrome Developer Console

I'm using the command `ws://localhost:3000` and getting the following error :
**VM44:1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000' failed**.

### Connection from NodeJS app with the following code :

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const serverAddress = 'ws://localhost:3000';

let client;

function createWebSocket() {
  client = new WebSocket(serverAddress);

  client.on('open', () => {
    console.log('WebSocket connection opened');
  });

  client.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log('Received message:', message);
  });
}

createWebSocket();
```

Giving the following error :

```
WebSocket connection closed
WebSocket error: Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:721:14)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:519:23)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1408:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

### Now this is my NestJS app config :

1. Gateway for Websocket *(imported in the providers[] of app.module)* :

```
import {
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway({ transports: ['websocket'] })
export class KoliWebSocketGateway
  implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect
{
  @WebSocketServer() server: Server;

  handleConnection(client: Socket) {
    console.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
    console.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
  }
}
```

2. My **main.ts** file

```
 const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new ExpressAdapter(server));

  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new IoAdapter(app));

  app.setGlobalPrefix('api/v1');
  app.enableCors({
    preflightContinue: false,
  });

  const swaggerConfig = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Koli API Reference')
    .setDescription('REST API for Koli app.')
    .setVersion('1.0.0')
    .build();

  const swaggerDocument = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, swaggerConfig);

  SwaggerModule.setup('reference', app, swaggerDocument);

  await app.listen(3000);"
```

### Versions

```
Ubuntu 20.04
Node.js v20.9.0
@nestjs/common: ^10.2.8
@nestjs/config: ^3.1.1
@nestjs/core": ^10.2.8
@nestjs/platform-express: ^10.2.8
@nestjs/platform-socket.io: ^10.2.8
@nestjs/websockets: ^10.2.8
socket.io: ^4.7.2
@nestjs/cli: ^10.2.1
```

Despite following the recommended practices and checking for potential errors/misconfigurations, I'm unable to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're using socket.io on the server side, you need to use socket.io-client on the client side to make the connection to the "socket" server. Socket.io does end up implementing websockets, but connecting directly with `ws` is not as simply supported. [You can read about some other approaches here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45327746)